# Issue with controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

```html
<body ng-controller="addressbookController">
    <div class="header">
        <h3>Address Book</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-bar">
        <ul>
            <li><a ui-sref="Index">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a ui-sref="OpenForm" id="add-link">+ADD</a></li>
            <li><img src="~/Content/Images/blog-icon.png" /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="contacts-container">
        <h3>CONTACTS</h3>
        <div class="contacts-list-container" >
            <ul ng-controller="detailController">
                <li ng-repeat="contact in contacts" class="list-style">
                    <a id={{contact.Id}} ui-sref="Details" ng-click="showContactDetail(contact.Id)">
                        <span class="list-name" ng-bind="contact.Name"></span>
                        <span class="list-phone-email">+91 {{contact.MobileNumber}}</span>
                        <span class="list-phone-email" ng-bind="contact.Email"></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div ui-view></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here I am getting the contacts from database and displaying it in the form of list and when I ever I click on one contact it should show the full details of the contact.

```html
<div class="details-container">
    <span class="detail-name" ng-bind="foundContact.Name"></span>
    <div class="delete-edit-container">
        <div class="edit-container">
            <a ng-click="editForm(foundContact.Id)" ui-sref="Edit">
                <img src="~/Content/Images/Edit-icon.png" style="height:15px;width:15px;" />
                <label>EDIT</label>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="delete-container">
            <a ng-click="delete(foundContact.Id)" ui-sref="Delete">
                <img src="~/Content/Images/delete1.png" style="height:20px;width:20px;" />
                <label>DELETE</label>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="detail-email">
            <label>Email:</label>
            <span ng-bind="foundContact.Email"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="detail-mobile-landline">
            <label>Mobile:+91 </label>
            <span ng-bind="foundContact.MobileNumber"></span><br>
            <label>Landline:</label>
            <span ng-bind="foundContact.LandlineNumber"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="detail-website">
            <label>Website:</label>
            <span ng-bind="foundContact.Website"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="detail-address">
            <label>Address:</label>
            <span ng-bind="foundContact.Address"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the details layout.

```
app.controller('detailController', ['$scope', '$state', 'UserServices', function ($scope, $state, UserServices) {
$scope.contact;
$scope.foundContact;
$scope.showContactDetail = function (id) {
    //$state.go('Details', { contactId: id });
    angular.element(document.getElementById(id)).addClass("highlight");
    UserServices.RemoveHighlight();
    UserServices.GetContactById(id).then(function (d) {
        $scope.foundContact = d.data;
    })
}
$scope.editForm = function (id) {
    UserServices.GetContactById(id).then(function (d) {
        $scope.contact = d.data;
    })
}
$scope.delete = function (id) {
    var contactId = id;
}
```

}]);

This is the detailcontroller where i am getting contact and assigning it to the foundcontact variable of partial view of showing details.

```
state('Details', {
    url: '/Details',
    templateUrl: 'Contact/Detail',
    controller: 'detailController'
}).
```

this is config.js file for showing details.

My problem when i am clicking on the contact link which is present in the first snippet empty layout is opening(without the contact data). when I debug i am getting the data into foundcontact of detailcontroller.

If I initialize foundcontact statically it is displaying the static data. If I am not initializing statically it is showing empty detail layout

Could anyone help me out this problem.

**Edit**

```
app.factory('UserServices', function ($http) {
var fact = {};
fact.GetContacts = function () {
    return $http.get('/Contact/GetContacts');   
}
fact.GetContactById = function (id) {
    return $http.get('/Contact/GetContactById/' + id);
}
fact.RemoveHighlight = function () {
    angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName('list-style')).removeClass("highlight");
}
return fact;
```

})

This is the userservices code.

Comment: share error details of console.log

Comment: I see the contact details data of the particular selected contact

Comment: no error in the console.log

Comment: could you please share the contact details json or its data structure

Comment: it is just an object with properties id, name, email, website, landlinenumber, mobilenumber, address which i am getting from database

Comment: one error I am seeing is , in ng-repeat you have mentioned contact in contacts and in the controller , you have used $scope.contact.. change $scope.contact to $scope.contacts to show contact details

Comment: that is not the controller where i am getting the contacts. There is another controller named  addressbookcontroller in which $scope.contacts is present. I think there is no problem with that view and controller as I am getting data in that view where i am getting data from ng-repeat

Comment: on clicking contact , you are calling $scope.showContactDetail function right??

Comment: yes calling that function which is in detailcontroller

Comment: Can you share the Userservices details?

Comment: is .highlight class has style display:none???

Comment: No, .highlight class has does not have style display:none. But the style is given to contactslist but not for contact layout.

Comment: Hope you did this https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial ? If not, it solves your problem.

Comment: No I have not done that tutorial. But I did this same addressbook without using routing and it work fine. But after adding routing I got this problem.

Comment: Use the [ng-class directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) to add/remove classes. It is properly integrated with the AngularJS framework and its digest cycle.

Comment: New AngularJS developers often do not realize that `ng-repeat`, `ng-switch`, **`ng-view`**, `ng-include` and `ng-if` all create new child scopes, so the problem often shows up when these directives are involved. See [AngularJS Wiki - Understanding Scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and not useful to other readers. The title of the question is too vague to be useful in a problem search.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue is with angular digest cycle.

Change your `showContactDetail` method signature as below :

```
$scope.showContactDetail = function(id) {
    //$state.go('Details', { contactId: id });
    angular.element(document.getElementById(id)).addClass("highlight");
    UserServices.RemoveHighlight();
    UserServices.GetContactById(id).then(function(d) {
        $scope.$evalAsync(function() {
            $scope.foundContact = d.data;
        });
    });
}
```